# We are unable to register default service worker. Failed to register ServiceWorker for scope The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im getting an error at the getToken function while configuring the push notification service. have need to integerate this to spring boot. so i just want to have token to create backend and test it.

the error is :

We are unable to register default service worker. Failed to register ServiceWorker for scope

The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

//app.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { initializedFirebaseApp } from './Firebase';
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";
const requestNotificationPermission = async (messaging) => {
  try {
    

const messaging = getMessaging();
    await Notification.requestPermission();
    const token = await getToken(messaging, {vapidKey: ""});
    console.log('Notification permission granted');
    console.log('FCM token:', token);
    // Send this token to your server to send notifications to this device
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting notification permission or FCM token:', error);
  }
};

const serviceWorkerPath = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/firebase-message-sw.js`;

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const messaging = initializedFirebaseApp.messaging();

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(serviceWorkerPath)
        .then((registration) => {
          console.log('Service Worker registered with scope:', registration.scope);
          requestNotificationPermission(messaging);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', err);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('Service Worker not supported');
    }
  }, []);

  // Rest of your component code

  return <div>Your App</div>;
};

export default App;

//firebase sw
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-messaging.js");


const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };
  

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const messaging = firebase.messaging(); 

//firebase config

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/messaging';

const firebaseConfig = {
 ...
};


// Initialize Firebase
const initializedFirebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
export { initializedFirebaseApp };
```